# JQuery AJAX POST produce null params in HttpServletRequest on Liberty profile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

I have an older JAX-RS application that I'm running on IBM Liberty profile 16.0.0.4 with the **jaxrs-2.0** feature.  I'm getting some weird behavior that I can't explain, and need some help.

JAX-RS service code:

```
@Path("/loadData") 
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
public String loadData(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    // add'l request processing code
}
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var reqData = {id:"123456", email:"user@email.com"};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:9080/jaxrs/loadData",
        data: reqData,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: "30",
        beforeSend: function() { ... },
        success: function(data) { .... },
        complete: function(data) { .... }
    });
});
```

JQuery (in IE) Results:

```
request.getParameter("id") or ("email") = null;
request.toString() = org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.HttpServletRequestFilter@f272c8dc
IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream) = "id=123456&email=user1%40email.com"
```

SoapUI Results:

```
request.getParameter("id") = 123456 and ("email") = user@email.com;
request.toString() = org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.HttpServletRequestFilter@de62638a
IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream) = ""
```

I compared the RAW HTTP request in SoapUI and in IE's console, they both appears to be the same, as far as I can tell.  So that's really got me confused, both JQuery and SoapUI are performing POST, but seems in IE's case the query stream is not being parsed into parameters, rather just maintained as a string.  I've tried to mess around with the contentType and request declaration with no effects.  I was originally using JQuery 1.7.1, but I tried on 3.1.1 with no effects.  Has anyone seen this before.  Any help or insights would be really great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using "JSON.strigify" for params

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var reqData = {id:"123456", email:"user@email.com"};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:9080/jaxrs/loadData",
        data: JSON.stringify(reqData),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: "30",
        beforeSend: function() { ... },
        success: function(data) { .... },
        complete: function(data) { .... }
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  The only thing I notice that's really different is SoapUI sets the request header's Content-Length attribute to "0".  I try to do that with JQuery, but it doesn't seem mutable.  I'm not sure if that's really what make it work, it's the only obvious difference in the HTTP header.  I've also looked at the request object on the server, for some reason, the CXF framework will not place the entire query string into the org.apache.cxf.message.Message.QUERY_STRING field in the request object, which does get set when SoapUI posts.